# linker error with templated friend function of templated class when using template independent enable_if

Tags: c++, templates, g++, friend-function

I'm dealing with a templated class with a templated friend function

```
template<typename T>
struct X {
  template<typename someX>
  auto friend f (someX x) -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<decltype(x.hidden), int>, int>;

private:
  T hidden = 42;
};

template<typename someX>
auto f(someX x) -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<decltype(x.hidden), int>, int> {return x.hidden;}
```

this compiles fine with g++, but fails at link time in

```
int main () {
  X<int> x;
  std::cout << f(x);
}
```

with

```
prog.cc:(.text+0x15): undefined reference to `std::enable_if<is_same_v<decltype ({parm#1}.hidden), int>, int>::type f<X<int> >(X<int>)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

[see here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/FpJnhlwYGbSzf37k).

What I observed is:

- when replacing the second argument of `enable_if` (the type) by something that depends on the class template (`int` → `decltype(x.hidden)`) [see here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/W69T6JPLIgxB3lb5) linking succeeds with g++.
- when making `hidden` public and dropping the friend declaration, the code links fine (so the function template gets instantiated).
- dropping the enable_if and just declaring the return type as `int` works fine.
- move the enable_if from the return type into the `template <typename … , typename = typename enable_if_t<…>>`, but here I fail to compile because g++ and clang++ tell me friend declarations do not allow default template arguments.
- drop the enable_if from the friend declaration and only keep it in the definiton → [fails to link](https://wandbox.org/permlink/q2D25i5iCLcuRd7u)
- when compiling with clang++ linking succeeds
- move the function definition into the class declaration (fails in the real world example, because the function is supposed to take various arguments as variadic template, and then i violate the one-definition-rule, having a `f(X<int>, X<float>)` defined once in the `X<int>` definition and once in the `X<float>` definition.

is this a g++ (8.2) bug or does clang++ violate the standard, and in the latter case, how do I trigger the code generation for the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is this a g++ (8.2) bug or does clang++ violate the standard

I suspect gcc is correct. Template friends are a dark corner of the language.

> how do I trigger the code generation for the function?

I'd do it via a befriended actor.

```
#include <iostream>

struct friend_of_f
{
    template<class someX> 
    static auto apply(someX x) -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<decltype(x.hidden), int>, decltype(x.hidden)>
    {
        return x.hidden;
    }
};

template<typename someX>
auto f(someX x) -> decltype(friend_of_f::apply(x))
{
    return friend_of_f::apply(x);
}

template<typename T>
struct X 
{

friend friend_of_f;

private:
  T hidden = 42;
};




int main () {
  X<int> x;
  std::cout << f(x);
  X<double> y;
//  std::cout << f(y);
}
```